# Execute a method once a day, at a specific time, on a running server in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

I have a web api that's running 24/7 on LAN(due to data security reasons, it's not connected to the internet). I have to call one method inside it each morning around 07:00. I've read that Timers are not reliable. I do not own the server so I don't have access to the Task Scheduler. How can I achieve this?

Do you think I should tell them that I have to install the software? Would they let me use the Task Scheduler? Is there any way to do this without the Task Scheduler?

Comment: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of options that you should look into.

- Native .NET Core solution through [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)
- [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire)

  - Personally, I like that you can configure a dashboard and see what happened during the execution of your scheduled tasks.
- As suggested by [@Lei Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518100/lei-yang) in the comments, [Quartz.NET](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet)

Hangfire is still adding in-memory support. Therefore, you're required to have a SQL Server to store all the information about the job (triggers, states, etc.).

This can have a huge impact in your decision. On the other hand, Quartz.NET does support in-memory store type.

Comment: Been playing around with quartz.net and hangfire for a bit. They seem like they will both do the job, I'll just have to decide which one is better for me. Thank you for the suggestions.